# JavaScript script doesn't execute

Tags: javascript, php, html

I've got this script and the following site. It seems very strange, the script doesn't even fire the first alert. If I replace the "update_table" function with an alert though, it displays the alert.

```
    <head>
    <script src="signals.js" type="text/javascript">
        update_table();</script>
</head>
<body>
```

Now this is from signals.js:

```
    function update_table()
{
    alert("h");
    var old_table = document.getElementById('signals').innerHTML;
    alert("h");
    var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
    alert("h");
    req.onreadystatechange = function(){
    if(req.status == 200)
    {
        if(req.readyState == 4)
        {
            var new_table = req.responseText;
            if(old_table != new_table)
            {
                //play sound
                alert("Sound!");
            }
            alert("Refresh!");
            setTimeout(update_table(), 5000);
        }
        }
    }
    var link = "table.php?refresh=true";
    alert("h");
    req.open("GET", link, true);
    req.send();
    alert("h");
}
```

Comment: have you intentionally didnt mentioned script tag around the function 'update_table'?

Comment: The function is taken from signals.js - no need for script tags!

Comment: You must not have a `src` attribute in an inline script. A script can only be either inline or external, not both. Use two separate script elements.

Answer (score 5):

You can not have script inside of a function that has an external source

```
<script src="signals.js" type="text/javascript">
    update_table();
</script>
```

needs to be two script tags.

```
<script src="signals.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
    update_table();
</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can't give a `<script>` element a `src` attribute **and** a script as a child text node. If you do, only the attribute will be honoured and the inline script will be ignored.

```
<script src="signals.js"></script>
<script>update_table();</script>
```

(assuming that the JS at the end of your code block represents the content of `signals.js` and not the HTML document body).

See also the [HTML 5 specification for the script element](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/scripting-1.html#the-script-element):

> **Content model**
>   If there is no src attribute, depends on the value of the type attribute, but must match script content restrictions.
>   If there is a src attribute, the element must be either empty or contain only script documentation that also matches script content restrictions.

Answer (score 2):

Your javascript needs to be in `<script>` tags.

Answer (score 1):

You need `<script>` tags around your javascript.

Also, you can't execute `update_table()` before defining it.

Answer (score 1):

You need to move the content of the script (`updateTable()`) after the script that includes signals.js:

```
<script src="signals.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>update_table();</script>
```

Relevant bit from w3:

> If the src has a URI value, user agents must ignore the element's
>   contents and retrieve the script via the URI.

http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/scripts.html#h-18.2.1

Answer (score 0):

Place the JS code in `<script>` tag and since you have cretaed a function, it needs to b triggered to perform action...somrthing like `<body onload=update_table()>`